# VB - how to detect certain words being typed?

Tags: vb.net, events

I have an array that contains the words "hello", "goodbye" and "ok". In **VB.NET**, how can I write a program that produces a message box every time one of these words is typed in, **WITHOUT** a button being clicked?

I did some research, and I came across the `keypress` event - however, this wouldn't be appropriate, because my program would become quite inefficient.

Is there a way in Visual Basic to detect certain words (in this case, in the array) to be detected, instead of just `keypress`'?

Comment: The TextChanged event would work. Then you can use the .Text property to see if it contains one of your words.

Comment: "because my program would become quite inefficient" - your computer can easily keep up with the keyboard. It's not a lot of overhead to test a short string on every keypress.

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it, but it brings about more problems...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim words As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(" "c)
        Dim detectWords As New List(Of String) From {"hello", "goodbye", "ok"}
        For Each word As String In words
            If detectWords.Contains(word.ToLower) Then
                MsgBox(word)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

With a keypress event, you could look for the enter key, then process it, instead of each time the text changes...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
            Dim words As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(" "c)
            Dim detectWords As New List(Of String) From {"hello", "goodbye", "ok"}
            For Each word As String In words
                If detectWords.Contains(word.ToLower) Then
                    MsgBox(word)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```